# Finding out two numbers(ratio and proportion)

Tags: ratio

There is a question in our book whose answer i am not being able to find out.:
Find two numbers such that the mean proportional between them is 28 and the third proportional to them is 224.

This is what I have done so far:

> Let the two numbers be $x$ and $y$. According to the question,
>   $$\frac x{28}=\frac{28}y$$
>   $$\implies xy=28^2=784\tag1$$
>   And
>   $$\frac xy=\frac y{224}$$
>   $$y^2=224x\tag2$$

What to do next?

Comment: (1) is $xy=784$ while (2) is $y^2=224x$. Get $x$ from (1) and subst into (2).

Comment: Okay... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

let the two numbers are a and b and their mean proportion is c . let the third proportion of a and b is d .
given c = 28 and d = 224
So a/28 = 28/b 
a*b = 28*28 --------------1) 
similarly a/b = b/224
so b^2 = 224a
a = b^2 /224-----------2) 
from eq 1 and 2
b^3 = 28*28*224 = 7^3 *8^3
b = 56 
so a = 28*28/56 = 14